# ResizeObserver not being triggered when content height changes (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, resize-observer

It works when I manually resize the window, but not when the content height changes which is what I need.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerRef = React.createRef();
    this.containerObserver = null;
    this.state = {
      top: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.containerObserver = new ResizeObserver((e) => this.handleResize(e));
    this.containerObserver.observe(this.containerRef.current);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.containerObserver) {
      this.containerObserver.disconnect();
    }
  }

  handleResize = (e) => {
    const { target } = e[0];

    const top = target.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = target.scrollHeight;
    const position = scrollHeight - top;
    const clientHeight = target.clientHeight;

    console.log({ top }, { scrollHeight }, { position }, { clientHeight });

    if (top < 10) {
      if (this.state.top) {
        this.setState({ top: false });
      }
    } else {
      if (!this.state.top) {
        this.setState({ top: true });
      }
    }

    if (position >= clientHeight - 40 && position <= clientHeight) {
      if (!this.state.top) {
        this.setState({ top: true });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container ref={this.containerRef} onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
          <Body />
        </Container>
        <ShadowTop show={this.state.top} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

--

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 760px) {
    position: absolute;
  }

  margin-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.percent}%;
  margin-top: -webkit-calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  margin-top: -moz-calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  margin-top: calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);

  height: ${({ theme }) => Math.abs(100 - theme.header.height.percent)}%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  height: calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);

  position: fixed;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: ${({ theme }) => 100 - theme.sidebar.width.percent}%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);
  width: calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);


  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: auto;
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using a `MutationObserver` with `subtree` enabled.

```
this.containerObserver = new MutationObserver(this.handleResize);
this.containerObserver.observe(this.containerRef.current, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
});
```

Comment: This sounds extremely expensive for what it accomplishes

Comment: @MichalKurz Any suggestions for an alternative approach?

Comment: Sure, I wrote one up as an answer, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You are observing `Container` for size change, but it has fixed dimensions:

```css
 height: ${({ theme }) => Math.abs(100 - theme.header.height.percent)}%;
 // ... 

 width: ${({ theme }) => 100 - theme.sidebar.width.percent}%;
```

so it never actually resizes, and resize observer never triggers.

Try wrapping its content inside an element that shrinks to the size of its content, and use the resize observer on this element instead:

```js
this.contentObserver.observe(this.contentRef.current);

// ...
<Container onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
   <ShrinkWrapper ref={this.contentRef}>
      <Body />
   </ShrinkWrapper>
</Container>
```

```js
const ShrinkWrapper = styled.div`
   width: fit-content;
   height: fit-content;
`
```